# Custom Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can see mention, but no example of being able to use an image to create a Google Map (Or at least use their API). From what I can work out you can use the ImageMapType class in the API to create a map, instead of earth (or and area), an image like JPEG. Is this correct or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I know for a fact this is possible, but I'm afraid it's been years since I implemented this.  For the record, I was able to make a custom map of the Pokemon world from the original red/blue games... yes, I am THAT big of a nerd.  Sorry I can't be of more help.  The source code is long gone by now, but I'll see if I can't dig it up from some old thumb drives...

Comment: Thanks Pete, I see there are a few people who have implemented maps for in game worlds. In fact having them for Pokemon all those moons ago would have been très useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Leaflet JS](http://leafletjs.com/) for this. I've used it for custom tiles and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the tutorial I followed years ago.  This should at least be a starting point... http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/custom-world-google-maps.php